# Moving MYSQL database Cache issue?

Tags: mysql, database, database-administration

I moved a mysql (myisam) database using rsync to aother server, I realized after doing this that I forgot to run 'flush tables' before moving the files so not all changes were written to disk I guess.

I did this out of hours but I was wondering how consistent the data will actually be after the move? Does mysql keep data in cache and also on disk or is everything that was in cache prior to the move lost?

Let me know if that doesnt make sense!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To reliably copy database tables, the database has to be stopped (not just flushed). If it is not, a consistent copy is not guaranteed, but is it impossible to say if and what data might be lost.

That said, if the database was not active and some time passed since the last write operation before you started the copy, it's likely the cache has been committed to the disk and if MySQL doesn't complain about damaged files during startup, you might be lucky.